# Clicking on a prefab causes it to appear in the scene

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm having a weird problem in Unity.  I'm working on a 2D scene, and when I select one specific prefab in the Project view, its sprite shows up in the Scene view.  However, it doesn't get added to the Heirarchy view, and it is not selectable in the Scene view (so it's not actually part of the scene).  I have a bunch of prefabs, and this behavior only happens with one of them.  Clicking on a different prefab will make the sprite for the original prefab go away, but after clicking back and forth several times, eventually the sprite stays there.  It'll even be visible while the game is playing.  It doesn't exhibit any of the game behavior that the associated prefab does, so it appears to just be a sprite and not an actual game object.  Restarting Unity is the only way to make it go away.

I've fiddled around with my prefab's components, and the problem seems to be caused when I have both an `Animator` (with a `Runtime Animator Controller`) and a `Sprite Renderer` both attached to my prefab.  I'm not sure why though.

Here's a screenshot showing the problem.  The two creatures that are not behind the camera are both prefabs (`NonPlayerCharacterPrefab` and `NonPlayerCharacterPrefab(1)` in the hierarchy view).  The creature behind the camera is what appears in the scene/game when I have the prefab highlighted in the Project view.  Even though the creature is visible in the scene, it's not part of the Hierarchy view.

[image]

I should note that I have the "Sprite Animation Preview" asset installed from the asset store.  I don't think that's causing the problem because that plugin shows animation previews in the Inspector, not the Scene view, but I'm mentioning it just in case it is somehow causing this.

I'm on version 2017.3.1f1

Has anyone encountered a problem like this, or does anyone have any ideas what's causing it?

Comment: My guess is that it's the Sprite Animation Preview ... thing. I was having an issue in a project where `GameObject.Find(...)` was pulling the wrong object, and it was finding an `xx(clone)AnimationPreview` copy (the searched-for object was a child of the cloned prefab).

Comment: I removed the Sprite Animation Preview from the Project view, but I'm still having the problem.  Is there something else that I have to do to correctly remove it from my project?  Another thing I noticed is that when I select the prefab in the Project view, a preview of the prefab isn't shown in the Inspector.  It's like Unity is showing the preview in the scene view instead of in the Inspector.

Comment: I think I figured it out.  I have both a `Sprite Renderer` and a `Line Renderer` attached to my prefab.  I've been using the `Line Renderer` to draw an in-game circle around the character.  It seems like having both renderers attached to the same object is what causes this.

Comment: You got me.  All I know is that I had weird behavior in my project caused by the Animation Preview.