# When clicking on a prefab it appears in the scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I found only one similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48959102/clicking-on-a-prefab-causes-it-to-appear-in-the-scene) but I have only a Sprite Renderer attached to my prefab.
[image]

[image]

Comment: You have an animator on it as well like the guy in the other post. Does this still happen if you take that off? Might be the animation preview causing it.

Comment: @RocketmanDan It does not help

Comment: Suggest you file a bug report with Unity, they're usually pretty responsive (they helped me out a few times).